# How to get uri for a pdf file stored in documents folder on android device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am trying to get the uri for the pdf document stored in documents folder on actual android device.

Actual doc path on device is
`/storage/emulated/0/Documents/testme.pdf`

[image]

to get the uri for this file this is the code I have tried

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == FILE_BROWSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            val uri: Uri? = data!!.getData() // - content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A30082


            val fileTest = File(uri!!.path) // /document/document:30082
            if(fileTest.exists() && fileTest.canRead()) { // both are FALSE
                Toast.makeText(context, "fileTest exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

getting the file from uri definitely is not the right way I am doing

how can I get the right uri please

your help is much appreciated

Thanks
R

Comment: "getting the file from uri definitely is not the right way I am doing" -- correct. "how can I get the right uri" -- you seem to have the right `Uri`, at least for how I would define "right".

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare thank you for responding,   if the uri is right fileTest.exists() && fileTest.canRead() should both return true but they return false for me any idea why

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. You cannot call `getPath()` on a `Uri` and get a filesystem path, because the user does not need to choose a file. Use the `Uri` properly, such as by using `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. This is not significantly different than using something like `HttpUrlConnection` to get an `InputStream` on content identified by a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a File from an Uri. An Uri can only be used by a DocumentFile.

The Uri you need is stored in your "uri" variable.

I recommend reading something about DocumentFiles here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scoped Storage API to get the document.

Just use the system file picker to get the URI.

1. Create a Contract class

```
class FilePickerContract : ActivityResultContract<Unit, List<Uri>>() {
  override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent =
      Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("*/*").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)

  override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): List<Uri> = if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || intent == null) {
    emptyList()
  } else {
    val uris = mutableListOf<Uri>()
    intent.data
        ?.let {
          uris.add(it)
        }
        ?: intent.clipData?.let { clipData ->
          for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
            uris.add(clipData.getItemAt(i).uri)
          }
        }
    uris
  }
}
```

2. Create an instance of the Contract

```
private val filePickerResultContract = registerForActivityResult(FilePickerContract()) { uris: List<Uri> ->
        if (uris.isNotEmpty()) {
            // do something with uris...
        } else {
            // no uris
        }
    }
```

3. Launch the contract

```
filePickerResultContract.launch(Unit)
```

You can read more about Android SAF [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)